# Winform SerialPort can't firing DataReceived

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            serialPort1.Open();
            serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort1_DataReceived);
            serialPort1.Write("test");
        }

        private void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //cant firing event
        }
    }
```

i already write some string to serialport but cant's firing DataReceived event??
[image: my serialport setting]

Comment: What do you expect to receive after writing "test" ? Do you have some device on the serial port that will react to the string "test"?

Comment: i have no device, so i need simulation device, how can i ????

Comment: What do you want to simulate? You could write a device simulator and have it run on another PC, then connect the two. If an echo-device is sufficient, then there are tutorials how to build one on the internet, but I don't think that's what you want. tl;dr: No Device => No Receive.

Comment: I guess you could also "loop-back" and run a simulator software on a different port instead of using a 2nd PC.

Comment: thanks man, i'll try